# SOLVED How to fix SpringSecurity dependency circle between UserDetailsService and inMemoryUserDetailsManager?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

EDIT (SOLVED):
I was able to fix it overriding UserDetailsService with the following impl:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Usuario user = this.usuarioRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (Objects.isNull(user))
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Usuário não encontrado: " + username);
        return new UserSpringSecurity(user.getId(), user.getUsername(), user.getSenha(), user.getProfiles());
    }
```

I'm getting a cycle error from SpringSecurity witch I can't seem to be able to fix. Can anyone help me out?

Console Error:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  securityConfig (field private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService api.Codigo.configs.SecurityConfig.userDetailsService)
↑     ↓
|  inMemoryUserDetailsManager defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class]
└─────┘

Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.

SecurityConfig Class

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import api.Codigo.security.JWTAuthenticationFilter;
import api.Codigo.security.JWTUtil;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JWTUtil jwtUtil;

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
        "/**"
    };

    @Bean
    @CrossOrigin
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
            CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
            configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
            configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
            configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
            // configuration.setAllowCredtesteentials(true);
            // configuration.setMaxAge(3600L);

            UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

            return source;
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()));
            http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

            AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
            authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
            this.authenticationManager = authenticationManagerBuilder.build();

            http.authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
            http
                    .sessionManagement(management -> management
                                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req.requestMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS)
                                            .permitAll()
                                            .anyRequest()
                                            .authenticated());
            
            
            http.addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(this.authenticationManager, this.jwtUtil));

            return http.build();
    }

    @Bean public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I tried ignoring it and allowing cycles, but then for some reason I wasn't able to authenticate users, so I rolled back to this error. I'm not really familiar with SpringSecurity so I'm a bit lost here...

Comment: There are so many tutorials for basic spring security usign jwt like [Spring Security](https://www.toptal.com/spring/spring-security-tutorial) Try it may be you will get some idea